# What does decoupling mean when studying fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, classical-field-theory

I just started studying field theory and general relativity, and when reading paper titles I often see the word decoupling coming up.

My intuition is that there must be a cross term involving some different fields in the lagrangian so they interact proportional to some constant and then to decouple you take the limit where the constant goes to zero. But I'm unsure if this is correct because the papers are unclear about the process of decoupling and Google is not helping.

I'm reading maggiore right now, there might be some info in there.

So what is a formal definition of decoupling and how do we proceed to study it?

Comment: "and then to decouple you take the limit where the constant goes to zero" -- this is *extremely* unlikely. What you're describing is just changing the problem to an easier one that has no bearing on what you originally wanted to describe.

Comment: The answer is probably along the lines of finding a transformation to new field coordinates where the cross-term disappears, in the same way that e.g. going to the normal-mode coordinates $X=x_1+x_2$, $x=x_1-x_2$ for a pair of coupled harmonic oscillators with $V= x_1^2+x_2^2+\lambda x_1 x_2$ produces two uncoupled harmonic oscillators in $X^2$ and $x^2$. (But I'm not an expert in that field, so I'll leave it for them to answer properly.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty okay I like the idea, but it's still unclear in a practical sense. I would like an actual example (on classical or quantum fields) to be certain about the actual definition and use. Thanks though.

Comment: This is an impossibly broad question. The [cynosure](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.11.2856) of the idea is the *Appelquist & Carazzone (1975) "Infrared singularities and massive fields" Phys Rev D 11(10), 2856* paper and the >2K papers citing it.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Sorry if it was too broad, I'm new to the subject and I see the word so often that I wanted a specific definition. Anyway, thanks for the resources.

Comment: It is normally covered in modern QFT texts. The original paper will give you an impression of the issues and the terminology. Try [this review](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.32506).